# Min and max from rand table with excluding interval in php

Tags: php, random

Hi I try return max value with excluding interwal.
I rand numers beetween 2000 and 2015 to table.
Next I return min and max value, but I want excluding interval beetween 2005 and 2010.
For example
When I rand 2000, 2004, 2006 I want that max will be 2004.
My actual try, doesn't work:

```
$tab = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $tmp = rand(2000,2015);
    $tab[$i] = $tmp;
}

$d = array_count_values($tab);
arsort($d);
$max = max(
    array_keys(
        array_filter(
            $d,
            function($y) {
                return $y < 2005 || $y > 2010;
            },
            ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
        )
     )
);
```

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Rand between 2000 an 2015. I have error: Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY - assumed 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY' in, Warning: array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in, Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in,Warning: max(): When only one parameter is given, it must be an array in and function nothing retun

Comment: Check your php version. From array_filter doc: "5.6.0 Added optional flag parameter and constants ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY and ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH"

Comment: Php version: 5.5.28. How do this in php 5.5?

Comment: I update my php version and code work. Thanks for helpo

Answer (score 2):

So, do you **really** can call a number that is smaller then 2005 **and** greater then 2010?

```
{ return $y < 2005 || $y > 2010; }
```

Also **note**, that if your php version is not `5.6` or `7` - you can't use `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` parameter.

**Update**:

```
$tab = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $tmp = rand(2000,2015);
    $tab[$i] = $tmp;
}

$d = array_count_values($tab);
arsort($d);

$max = max(
    array_filter(
        array_keys($d),
        function($y) {
            return $y < 2005 || $y > 2010;
        }
    )
);
echo $max;
```

Comment: I understand my error with return $y < 2005 || $y > 2010; I edit code 
but it still does not work

Comment: Sure your php is 5.6? Turn on `error_reporting` also.

Comment: @vjdj Are you sure? I am using your code (with the correction) here and it is working ok.

Comment: Php version: 5.5.28 and error_reporting(0); max return nothing. How do this in php 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
<?php
$tab = array();
for($i=0; $i<10;$i++)
{
    $tmp = rand(2000,2015);
    $tab[$i]=$tmp;
}
$intersect = array();
foreach (range(2005, 2010) as $number) {
    $intersect[] = $number;
}
$result = array_diff($tab, $intersect);
echo max($result);
echo "<br>";
echo min($result);
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Good idea. I believe you can use `range(2005, 2010)` directly in the `array_diff` without building `$intersect` from the range.

Answer (score 0):

This will always evaluate as false:

```
return $y < 2005 && $y > 2010;
```

You want:

```
return $y < 2005 || $y > 2010;
```

Or

```
return !($y >= 2005 && $y <= 2010);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $tmp = rand(2000,2015);
    if($tmp > 2010 || $tmp < 2005){
        $tab[$i] = $tmp;
    }
}

    if( count($tab) > 0){
    echo "max value - ".max($tab).'</br>';
    echo "min value - ".min($tab).'</br>';
    }
```